# iOS UIAppearance custom shape for widgets

Tags: ios, shapes, uiappearance

I've been looking at a lot of sample code out there for UIAppearance, and there seem to be a lot of examples, where widgets and status bars are a different colour, or a nice background image, but, how does one create things that are a different shape??  For example, have a look at this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOoWa.jpg - this is a screen shot from a utility app.  How does one make these kinds of buttons and especially switches (once one obviously has the artwork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use transparency. Just create an rectangular image with an asymmetrical button in it an make all space you don't use for your button transparent. Now create a new button in the interface-builder, set the type to custom and attach your created image to the button as background.

On the other hand u can just modify standard controls. I don't know if it's possible to manipulate the UISwitch-control directly, but i did this by my self with the UISlider to create a look-a-like of the slide-to-unlock control.

For example:

`[slider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderButton_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  UIImage *minTrackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Clearpixel.png"];
  [slider setMinimumTrackImage:minTrackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [slider setMaximumTrackImage:minTrackImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Will look like:

[slider.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzNL3.png)

without the background.